# Auto show text when user type duplicate key in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I need some help with my project, when i type in textbox (primary key - textbox), if it is duplicated key in mysql, it will show text next to textbox like this (not click button, it will show auto when i type: ABC12444 -> this record is exist in system):

[image]

My code:

```
 $idcustomer = $_POST['txtIDCus'];
 $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM customer where id='$idcustomer' ");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $errMsg="Key exist in system";
    }
```

Simple HTML Code

```
<b>ID Customer:</b>
<input type="text" id="txtIDCus" name="txtIDCus" width="100" placeholder="Type ID Customer" size="40" class="form-control" maxlength="70"/> <br />
```

I try to show my stuck, hope you help me. Thanks!

Comment: catch keyup + xmlhttprequest thru javascript

Comment: Can you put your HTML code ?

Comment: I'm update HTML code, it so simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using jquery..
I hope this helps..

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="key" /> <span id="key-result"> </span>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#key").on("input", function() {
        var key = this.value;
        //you can skip using timeout just call check_key_ajax(key);
        x_timer = setTimeout(function(){check_key_ajax(key)}, 1000);            
    });

function check_key_ajax(key){            
        $.post('checkKey.php', {'Key':key}, function(data) {$("#key-result").html(data);});            
    }
```

Checker.php

```
    if(isset($_POST["Key"]))
    {
    $idcustomer = $_POST["Key"];
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM customer where id='$idcustomer'");
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $errMsg="Key exist in system";
        echo $errMsg;
    }
}
```